# How to backup table to local disk using mysql event

Tags: mysql

I am trying to backup one database table to my local path as .sql file using below mysql command,

```
create event backupIn_home_Directory_sqlfile on every 1 day
starts '2015-10-14 16:10:00'
do
select * into outfile 'C:\Users\username\Desktop/backupcehcking.sql' from testingDB.table_test;
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual    that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'every
 1 day starts '2015-10-15 13:10:00' do select * into outfile 'C:\Users\user' at
line 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

As per Answer i changed the command,

```
mysql> alter event backupIn_home_Directory_sqlfile do select * into outfile 'C:\
Users\RAGHU_ZANCT\Documents\DBbackup_Checking\backupcehcking.sql' from testing.m
anitest;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter event backupIn_home_Directory_sqlfile on schedule every 1 day start
s '2015-10-15 15:28:00';
```

Eventhough i dont find that backupcehcking.sql file in that specific folder. why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot `SCHEDULE`

use this:

```
create event backupIn_home_Directory_sqlfile on schedule every 1 day
```

Example Syntax:

```
CREATE EVENT event_name
   ON SCHEDULE
     EVERY 1 DAY
   COMMENT 'Optinal comment goes here'
   DO
     YOUR QUERY;
```

Comment: ya you are correct I missed that schedule. Now event created but i dont see that backupcehcking.sql file in that specific path.

Comment: I tink all the slashes should be same `C:\Users\username\Desktop\backupcehcking.sql`

Comment: i did alter event to C:\Users\username\Desktop\backupcehcking.sql even i dont find backupcehcking.sql file there. :( where am doing mistake?

Comment: Can you try another location because there might be some permission issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92369/discussion-between-m-manivasagam-and-madforstrength).